# DynamoDB hash key assignment

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm reading about DynamoDB, and I saw [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.01.html) to create a table called `Movies`

But, if by mistake I put a movie with wrong `Year` in his propertie (`Year` is a Hash Key), how can I update this wrong register puting the right year in this propertie that is a Hash Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the sort key value. You have to delete the item and create it again.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html

Comment: I tested this now and the return for this operation is: "You cannot modify the unique keys of your item! If you would like to create a similar item, use the copy item function or manually override the item values"